# SOQL to get 3 months no stage movement on the opptuity

Tags: soql, batch

I want to make a batch class to auto closed lost opportunity if 3 months no stage movement

Now I made this SOQL in `Database.QueryLocator` `start`:

`SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityFieldHistory WHERE Field = 'StageName' AND (CreatedDate <= :Date.today().addMonths(-3))) AND LeadSource = 'Inbound' AND StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost')`

But I just realized that /i should add `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1` on `select OpportunityFieldHistory` to get the latest stage history, but I got error if I put that in SOQL.

And this SOQL also does not provide if there is no stage changed in opportunityFieldHistory (initial created and then not move the stage at all)

How can I provide this?

Comment: What is the error message?  Please [edit] your post to include the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the opportunities that have no stage movement for the last 3 months, you can use a SOQL query that filters the opportunities based on their last stage change date and their current stage. For example, you can use the following query:

> SELECT Id, Name, StageName, LastStageChangeDate FROM Opportunity
> WHERE LastStageChangeDate <= LAST_N_MONTHS:3 AND StageName != 'Closed
> Won' AND StageName != 'Closed Lost'

This query will return the id, name, stage name, and last stage change date of the opportunities that have not changed their stage in the last 3 months and are still open. You can modify the query to include other fields or criteria as needed.

Object Document:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm